# What are the etymological origins of the names Muhammad, Jesus and Buddha?

Tags: etymology, names, religion

Muhammad, Jesus and Buddha are names today strongly connected with the religions these guys founded. So obviously they were not derived from their respective religions. So what did these names signify when their parents gave them those names?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to ELU. Please remember that askers should show [a reasonable amount of research](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and explain how their research has not been satisfactory in answering the question. In this case, the etymologies you’re looking for can be found on the Wikipedia pages for [Muhammad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad#Quranic_names_and_appellations), [Jesus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesus#Etymology), and [the title Buddha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddha_(title)#Etymology), which I’m afraid makes the question off-topic here.

Comment: "Obviously"? I don't follow.

Answer (score 4):

**[Muhammad](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Muhammad)** - Etymology: Borrowed from **Arabic**‎‏ ﻣُﺤَﻤَّﺪ (muhammad, “praised, commendable, laudable”), the passive participle of ﺣَﻤَّﺪَ (hammada, “to praise, commend, laud, extol”). From the same triconsonantal root ﺡ ﻡ ﺩ (h-m-d) as, but distinct from, Mahmud.

**[Jesus](https://www.etymonline.com/word/jesus)** - Etymology: the **Greek** form of "Joshua", the Late Latin form of "Iesus" (properly pronounced as three syllables), from Greek "Iesous", which is an attempt to render into Greek the Aramaic (Semitic) proper name Jeshua (Hebrew Yeshua, Yoshua) "Jah is salvation."

**[Buddha](https://www.etymonline.com/word/buddha)** - Etymology: from **Pali**, literally "awakened, enlightened," past
participle of budh "to awake, know, perceive," which is related
to Sanskrit bodhati "is awake, observes, understands," from PIE (Proto Indo European)
root "bheudh": "be aware, make
aware." Title given by his
adherents to the man who taught this path, Siddhartha Gautama, also known to them as Sakyamuni "Sage of the
Sakyas" (his family clan), who lived in northern India 5c. B.C.E.

Comment: Can you add a more direct answer to the OP? Namely, what did they _signify_ when their parents gave them these names? That is, they probably meant nothing at all in the first two instances because given names are usually opaque (even when they are ostensibly actual words, e.g. Grace, Frank). In the last instance, Buddha, Siddhartha's parents didn't name him Buddha.

Comment: Right, Mitch.  Jesus's parents didn't name him *Christ* ("annointed") either.

Comment: Did they have any roots in previous religions?

Comment: Note that Buddha was a taken name, for Prince Siddharth Gautama. It is a name taken much like you would address a teacher as, “Teacher”.

Comment: LocalFluff, "Joshua" was--according to Hebrew myth & legend--the hero who led the Israelites into the land of Canaan after their flight from Egypt.  He was Moses's successor, and his exploits are recorded in the sixth book of the Bible, which bears his name.